# While publishing a project, classes in AppCode folder did not complied

Tags: visual-studio, iis, model-view-controller, publish, app-code

I want to publish a mvc web project on visual studio IDE. In the project, here is one class in the AppCode folder. But after publish / build the project, there is no `.dll` file for this folder. As a result, the folder did not compile.

I clicked Publish and selected Configuration is release as a settings of publish. I build all solution files more than one time.

I expected `.dll` file for AppCode classes but after publishing AppCode folder created and it includes `.cs` file. As a result there is no dll file for this folder.

Answer (score 2):

I solved my problem with Publish settings. On File Options part, I checked "Precomplied during publish" option.

Then I saw that App_Code folder complied.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to complie the AppCode classes, I suggest you could try to follow below steps:

1) Right click on your class file in App_Code folder.

2) Click on properties.

3) Change Build Action to Compile

4) Build your App.

[image]

Then it will build into your project.dll, since asp.net will combine all the codes into one dll.

Like below:

The Te is the App_Code class name.

[image]

Comment: I tried this but got 500 error. Normally, when Build Action was Content, I complied without error and also did not create App_Code folder after publishing. By the way, i do not see your images.

Comment: Could you please tell me the details 500 error? I used the SO build-in upload image faeture. The link is https://i.stack.imgur.com/Moboy.png,https://i.stack.imgur.com/KHc2J.png

Comment: Source of 500 error is A class file in App_Code folder did not complied so I got an error.